# output from CryptGenRandom

Tags: windows, key-generation, entropy

Can we capture the output of Windows CryptGenRandom function. 
Suppose an application is utilizing CryptGenRandom, as a user can we know what is the Random Number generated and given to the application

Comment: Is the question complete? It reads like a bit is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the environment in which the application runs — basically, if you have access to the account under which the application runs — then you can observe everything it does. Simply run the application under a debugger and put a breakpoint or a trace on calls to `CryptGenRandom`.

If you don't have control over the execution of the program, then you can't capture the output of this or any other function. The alternative would be to predict the output. You can't predict the output of `CryptGenRandom`, because it's a crypto-quality random number generator and it isn't implemented so badly as to be completely broken. The whole point of crypto-quality randomness is that it's unpredictable. The only way to predict the value would be to have access to all the sources of entropy of the machine and to know all the times when `CryptGenRandom` is called so that you can recreate the state of the RNG. In practice, if you can do that, you can run a debugger.